# Unclassifiable Statement at (1), Fortran90 error

Tags: fortran95

I keep getting this error when I try to compile. I am not quite sure what the issue is. I am not the best at coding, and thus, debugging is not my strong suit. Any ideas whats causing the error?

```
PROGRAM Atmospheric_Reflection
    IMPLICIT NONE

    REAL*8:: Wavelength = 0.200D-6, WaveNumber = 0.0, pi = 3.14159265, Length(1:71) = 0, Number(1:71) = 0, IndexOfRe(1:71) = 0
    INTEGER:: i = 0


    !Calculate the wave number for wavelengths varying from 0.2 micrometers to 1.6 micrometers  in increments of 0.02 micrometers
    i = 1

    DO WHILE (Wavelength <= 1.600D-6)
        WaveNumber = 1/Wavelength
        Length(i) = Wavelength
        Number(i) = WaveNumber
        IndexOfRe(i) = 1 + (((5791817.0/(238.0185 - WaveNumber**2))+(167909.0/(57.362-WaveNumber**2))))D-8
        Wavelength = Wavelength + 0.02D-6

        i = i+1
    END DO
END PROGRAM
```

Comment: To get the best help, you should indicate at which line the error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the D-8 at the end of this line

```
IndexOfRe(i) = 1 + (((5791817.0/(238.0185 - WaveNumber**2))+(167909.0/(57.362-WaveNumber**2))))D-8
```